# How do you write incremental models in DBT?

Tags: dbt

I have two large tables I'm trying to join & filter using dbt.

The SQL is very simple, roughly:

```
SELECT
   u.user_id, t.transaction_id
FROM users u
JOIN transactions t ON t.user_id = u.user_id
WHERE u.active = 1
```

Currently I'm using the "table" materialization, but this is fairly wasteful, as the tables underlying tables are 99.99% the same from run to run.

However, I don't understand from the DBT documentation how I could set this model to "incremental".

Any ideas?

PS. I'm running on SQL Server.

Comment: can you share how you know if a row is new or not? is there a `primary_key` in the table an `date_last_updated`? That's the first thing you'll need. Perhaps `transaction_id` is unique?

Comment: I don't. Unfortunately we are sourcing this data from a vendor, and the way they keep it up to date is they executed arbitrary write/update/delete against our database. I could hook into the db log to get this data, but that'd be a pain.

Comment: @MYK did either of the answers help you out?

Comment: Thanks for the prompt. I've accepted your answer. I've not tried it yet, but it looks like it should work.

Comment: Awesome, thanks! Please come back if you run into more trouble with this.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As @anders-swanson wrote in his comment, if `transaction_id` is definitely unique, you could set it as the `unique_key` and materialize your model as an incremental table.

[dbt's docs](https://docs.getdbt.com/docs/building-a-dbt-project/building-models/configuring-incremental-models#defining-a-uniqueness-constraint-optional) explain how to do this. Using your example, it might be:

```
{{
    config(
        materialized='incremental',
        unique_key='transaction_id'
    )
}}

select
   u.user_id, t.transaction_id
from users u
join transactions t ON t.user_id = u.user_id
where u.active = 1
```

If `transaction_id` is not unique but `transaction_id`||`user_id` is, you could try creating a new column which concatenates these columns in an upstream dbt model, and then assigning that as the `unique_key`:

```
{{
    config(
        materialized='incremental',
        unique_key='pkey'
    )
}}

select
   u.user_id, 
   t.transaction_id,
   u.user_id||t.transaction_id as pkey
from users u
join transactions t ON t.user_id = u.user_id
where u.active = 1
```

Otherwise, you'll have to pull in a column that is either a) unique, or b) has an ordered quality that could be used to apply an `is_incremental()` filter (like @viacheslav-nefedov wrote).

Comment: DBT recommended practice is to provide a list of columns which ensure uniqueness - https://docs.getdbt.com/docs/build/incremental-models#about-incremental_strategy
In cases where you need multiple columns in combination to uniquely identify each row, we recommend you pass these columns as a list (unique_key = ['user_id', 'session_number']), rather than a string expression (unique_key = 'concat(user_id, session_number)').

Answer (score 3):

If you have a date field you can use it to load only the last data.
I.e. you have transaction_date column.

```
{{ config(
  materialized='incremental',
    as_columnstore=false, 
  pre_hook="""
    {% if is_incremental() %}
      delete from {{this}} 
      where transaction_date >= '{{ (modules.datetime.datetime.now() - modules.datetime.timedelta(2)).isoformat() }}'
    {% endif %}  
  """
)}}

SELECT
   u.user_id, t.transaction_id
FROM users u
JOIN transactions t ON t.user_id = u.user_id
WHERE u.active = 1

{% if is_incremental() %}
 and transaction_date >= '{{ (modules.datetime.datetime.now() - modules.datetime.timedelta(2)).isoformat() }}'
{% endif %}
```

The first time you run this model it will ignore all the code under "if is_incremental()". All the upcoming runs it will clean up transactions for the last two days and reload them.